# Counting preprocessor macro possible?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to create a C preprocessor macro that evaluates to an increasing number depending on how often it was called? It should be compile-time only.

I'd like something like:

```
#define INCREMENT() ....
#define INCRVALUE ....

INCREMENT()
INCREMENT()
i = INCRVALUE;
// ...
INCREMENT()
// ...
j = INCRVALUE;
```

and afterwards i == 2 and j == 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C Preprocessor: Own implementation for \_\_COUNTER\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693565/c-preprocessor-own-implementation-for-counter)

Answer (score 5):

The C pre-processor works with text. It can't do any kind of arithmetic because it does not know how and even if it did, you can't assign to rvalues like literals (e.g. `5 = 5+1` or `++5`).

A `static` variable would be much better.

GCC provides a macro, `__COUNTER__`, which expands to an integer representing how many times it's been expanded but that's not ISO C.

```
#define CNT __COUNTER__
#define INCREMENT() CNT

INCREMENT();
INCREMENT();
int i = CNT;  
// i = 2
```

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/counter.html) may help if you need it to be portable.

Comment: I was hoping the macro could add the string "+1" each time. But thank you for __COUNTER__.

Comment: That's not possible because the preprocessor can't make additions. Are we still talking about integers or strings?

Comment: I was hoping that the preprocessor could create something like 1+1+1 and adding "+1" every time the macro is used. The compiler would then at compile time do the addition and create an integer.